# My website return HTTP error 500 when closed on browser and then re -open IIS 7.5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I used cookies formsauthentication on my mvc 4 project. When I successfully log in to my site,the cookie is stored on the browser as authentication ticket, and then i closed the tab and then i access again my site and returns http 500 error page not found. I have made my cookie authentication persistent on my code. to make my site able to acccess again i go to browser settings and remove the cookies stored and then its ok. how do make site auto remove cookie when tab is closed or when my site is close in browser so that i dont have to remove cookies all the time from my browser. I am using IIS 7.5 Asp.net mvc 4

Comment: autoremoving the cookie is an ugly hack. Spin up your debugger to find out where the exception is thrown and how you should handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out why it returns and error, just because i am using a static variable in my condition on layout page,there are no arguments that supports the condition when the second user happens to access my app.

```
else if ((RMIS.Models.Global.UserLogName != null && ViewBag.Active == "Main")
{
 @RenderBody()
}
```

Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting 500 error because there is something wrong with your server side code.

And for clearing your cookie try this. [detail](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/423515/clearing-cookies-on-closing-browser-tab)

```
 <body onunload="deleteAllCookies()">

function deleteAllCookies() {
    var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");

    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
        var cookie = cookies[i];
        var eqPos = cookie.indexOf("=");
        var name = eqPos > -1 ? cookie.substr(0, eqPos) : cookie;
        document.cookie = name + "=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";
    }
}
```

Comment: ok I'll try that, but do that onunload event in the body tag  fires everytime I navigate to a new page? or it triggers only when user closes the browser tab or the entire browser

Comment: It will be called if you try to close the page or tab or if you have hit the back icon on your browser

Comment: and one thing more, i also need to manage my site on IIS ,stopping my site and then restart to make it accessible again. everytime i close the site without logging out and then i try to access again the site it returns an error http 500 page not found

Comment: Never used IIS sorry but if this what you were looking for dont forget to accept the answer. ;)